# Trying to update a vimeo regex to get the ID from URL which includes "channels/staffpicks"

Tags: javascript, regex, url, vimeo, capture-group

I have a vimeo regex which works in getting the ID from a standard URL: `https://vimeo.com/42100325`

I can't get it work when the URL is: `https://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/142100325`

This is what I have at the moment:

```
var vimeoId = /\/\/(?:www\.)?vimeo.com\/([0-9a-z\-_]+)/i;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only interested in the part at the end, there is no reason to describe the whole string in the regexp:

```
var vimeoId = /([0-9a-z\-_]+)$/i;
```

Comment: You legend, this also solves the problem of other /chanels/etc/ in the URL's. Perfect. Once the time limit is up I'll mark as correct :)

Comment: I presume this can work for any URL where I just need to get the last part of it?

Comment: yes. Maybe you take some time to look into regular expressions a bit. For example: markers like "$" (end of string) or "^" (start of string) make it very easy to retrieve data from strings in such special cases - without having to worry about, how the string is build up en detail.

Comment: You can try `/[^/]+$/`

Comment: @hjpotter92: nice add. but remember to escape the slash: [^\/]+$

Comment: @StefanDochow Not necessary when something is inside a character set.

Comment: @hjpotter92: intersting, it throws an error at https://regex101.com/ .but works here: https://jsfiddle.net/e63ynvtu/

Comment: regex101 is a 3rd party application.

Answer (score 2):

Try the pattern:

```
var vimeoId = /\/\/(?:www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(?:channels\/staffpicks\/)?([-\w]+)/i;
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work - I'm going to mark the other answer as correct only because it solves a few other issues too :)